# Parsing AngularJS http.post data on server side with express & body-parser

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, express, body-parser

I just recently started learning MEAN stack so forgive me if this seems like a really dumb question. My problem is as follows:

On the client side (controller.js) I have,

```
  $http({
  method  : 'POST',
  url     : '/root',
    // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
  headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
  data    :  {
              type:'root',
              username:$scope.rEmail,
              password:$scope.rPassword
            }

 })
```

On the server side I have,

```
app.post('/root', function(req, res) {

  console.log(req.body);

  console.log(req.body.username);
});
```

My console log shows:

```
17 Nov 21:39:04 - [nodemon] starting `node server/server.js`
{ '{"type":"root","username":"testUserName","password":"testPassword"}': '' }
undefined
```

I would imagine req.body.username to give me testUserName but I get undefined. The JSON format I am getting is slightly weird. Can anyone help me out this one? I did some reading and tried using body-parser and went through angular js $http.post documentation but didn't find anything that would help me out.

I imagine the problem is at:

```
 { '{"type":"root","username":"testUserName","password":"testPassword"}': '' }
```

but I cant seem to figure out how I would pass the data from $http.post in my angular controller so that I would just get my request in identifier:value format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out. Seems like I needed a break from coding.

```
headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
```

to

```
headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
```

fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try my source code below:

```
$http({
  method  : 'POST',
  url     : '/root',
    // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
  headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
  data    :  {
              type:'root',
              username:$scope.rEmail,
              password:$scope.rPassword
            },
  transformRequest: function(obj) {
      var str = [];
      for(var p in obj){
          str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
      }
      return str.join('&');
  }

 })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$http({
  method  : 'POST',
  url     : '/root',
    // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
  headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
  params    :  {
              type:'root',
              username:$scope.rEmail,
              password:$scope.rPassword
            }

 })
```

try it with 'params', maybe it won't work but try it :P

Answer (score 0):

I've tried with "params" instead of "data" and worked ok, and doesn't matter if headers are "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" or "application/json"
But using "application/json" works with request.query.param1 on node.